# margin problem in css while using position element

Tags: html, css, position

I am pretty new to web development so I am facing a margin issue which I think I might be due to position element in css,I'm not sure though .Here in code I have posted below is just a code for practice purpose on position element in css.
Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Position Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <span class="title-text">Position Demo</span>
    </header>
    <div class="container-1"></div>
    <div class="container-2"></div>
</body>
```

And here's my css code:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title-text {
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container-1 {    <!-- this container has right margin even though I have set margin to 0--> 
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(218, 173, 173);
}

.container-2 {   <!-- this container has right margin even though I have set margin to 0-->
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(149, 218, 183);
}
```

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: It is the [*used*](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#used-values) right margin, automatically changed from 0 because the dimensions of the in-flow non-replaced block-level box are [over-constrained](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#blockwidth)

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing in inspect mode, is not margin.

[image]

Just to make sure:

[image]

Each element, without changing the display property of the parent element, is placed below it's sibling element. I mean elements are displayed in the page based on their place in your html.
That's why browser shows that yellowish line right of the boxes, it means that this line is taken.
I suggest you set the display property for each section in html.

Comment: Do not confuse the *computed* margin value, which is what you see in the inspector window, with the *used* margin value, which is what the orange/yellowish box depicts.

Comment: @Alohci can you tell the difference between the two u just told

Comment: @charles - Broadly, its just a multi step process. The declared values get resolved a specified value by the cascade, the specified value gets some calculations done to it, e.g. converting `em`s to `px`s and becomes the computed value. This value is the one that gets inherited by child elements if necessary. Then more calculations are performed to produce the used value, including converting any remaining "auto" values to real values. And finally that gets converted to an actual value to account the physical capabilities of the device.

Comment: See [Computed Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#computed) and [Used Value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#used).

Comment: @Alohci That's very useful info thnx.